# Tamper data post parameters to prove the NULL pointer case ( JAVA JSP)

Tags: java, jsp, tampering, post-parameter

There was a NULL pointer exception occurred in production I am trying to replicate the run time exception  in my local system.  I am actually using the fire fox  tamper tool to intercept the post  parameters. I entered NULL values in  the  tamper window and submit the request to serer side code.

Post parameter are  ccNumber , ccYear and ccMonth. all these variables are defined in  JSP page. this is a legacy code developed a way back so you see hell lot of scriptlet code in jsp

On the webpage page after user submits the credit card number, month and year fields we use AJAX to post the parameters to the below JSP page. I am actually intercept the request parameters using fire fox tamper data and sets all these values to null and submit the tamper data.. but interestingly the values are  coming as null in JSP page but didn't throw the NULL pointer exception if I use  ccNumber.lenghth () method , instead it shows the length as 4. Am am setting the right values in tamper tool window ?? I am just changing the parameter value to null,perhaps this isn't correct?

Why the value is not coming as null in JSP page??

## Payment.jsp

```
 ccNumber = (request.getParameter("ccNumber"));
 ccExpireMonth = (request.getParameter("ccExpireMonth"));
 ccExpireYear = (request.getParameter("ccExpireYear"));
 ccType = (request.getParameter("ccType"));

 If ( cisCardNotVlaid) 
  { 

   ccNumber .length () == 0  // this suppose to throw the NULL pointer exception .
```

Answer (score 0):

To have `request.getParameter("anyParameter")` return `null`, just don't specify the parameter at all.

Comment: You pass on "null" as parameter, not the actual `null` value. To really get `null`, delete the parameter from the parameter list.
Just right-click and choose "remove element" or something similar

Comment: I don't have  "remove element" or anything of the sort on my right-click menu.  I can add, but not remove...